# Completed Installing Ubuntu 12.10 but couldn't boot to Ubuntu

Tags: installation, 12.10

I tried to install the Dual-OS, Ubuntu and Windows 8 by using a USB drive. I followed every step and finished installing Ubuntu, then it asked me to restart computer.

So I did and after reboot I took me to the same screen when I first want to download Ubuntu. Only show.

1. > Try Ubuntu without installing
2. > Install Ubuntu....

Is is supposed to show me a selection of either Ubuntu or Windows to run? I have Ubuntu run along with Windows on my Laptop, and I never had this problem.

Comment: Did you remove USB drive? If your boot priority set to USB you will not enter the Grub before remove it.

Answer (score 0):

Where did you install your boot loader? If you installed it in a different drive than windows, use BCedit to add a boot entry. Otherwise follow your boot order as mentioned above